# How to replace NOT EXISTS nested select with JOIN

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Hey there, I'm kinda stuck trying to optimise a query which has a NOT EXISTS clause on a nested SELECT. I've been rewriting my queries containing nested selects, changing them to joins, but on this occasion I'm not sure how to combine that with the NOT EXISTS clause. I have the following query:

```
SELECT `reg_no`, COUNT(*) AS `records_found` 
FROM (`club_records` AS `cr`) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
  SELECT `number` FROM `members` WHERE `members`.`number` = `cr`.`alt_reg_no` 
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

```
SELECT `reg_no`, COUNT(*) AS `records_found`,members`.`number`
FROM `club_records` AS `cr`
LEFT OUTER JOIN members`
ON  `members`.`number` = `cr`.`alt_reg_no
WHERE members`.`number` IS NULL;
```

attention:
member number definition must include NOT NULL constraint

Comment: Thanks! Set the member number column to NOT NULL and this works great